# create an anchor tag for wmv file that works on all browsers

Tags: html, video

I want to add a link(wmv file) to my page that would work across all the browsers. Currently, the link is embedded automatically on the page in IE8. I could add an object tag with object type="video/x-ms-wmv" but that would work only in windows not on mac.

```
<a  href="http://mylink.wmv">My video</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`wmv` is a proprietary media format that is only supported by certain plugins. You will not get universal support for it.

If you want to embed video with good browser support then you need to use a [mixture of codecs and container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support).

You can use HTML 5 video with webm for most, falling back to HTML 5 video with h.264 for a couple of browsers, and then Flash for everything else.